# Turn my time into a timestamp php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a current time formatting method which is:

```
$time = date('mdY');
```

And i need to turn this back into a normal linux timestamp. I need to do this on the fly. Basically a function is getting $time passed to it, then it needs to convert it into a normal timestamp (which i am assuming is time();)?

Thank you

**EDIT:
When I try everyone obvious suggestion, I get a 
Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/50/5975650/html/checkEntry.php on line 75**

```
function RelativeTime($timeToSend){
    $difference = time() - $timestamp;
    $periods = array("sec", "min", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "years", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    if ($difference > 0) { // this was in the past
        $ending = "ago";
    } else { // this was in the future
        $difference = -$difference;
        $ending = "to go";
    }
    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    $difference = round($difference);
    if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
    $text = "$difference $periods[$j] $ending";
    return $text;
}
```

// Check Service Call Status & Mail if found Unpaid

```
$query = "SELECT id, account, status, dateEntered FROM service WHERE status = 'Unpaid'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                $account = $row[1];
                $status = $row[2];
                $dateEntered = $row[3];

                $timestamp = strtotime($dateEntered);   
                            $timeToSend = RelativeTime($timestmap);

              // mailStatusUpdate($account, $status, $timeToSend);

        }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but there are 
*so* many duplicates of this on Stack Overflow. Plus, entering your question title into Google also finds the answer:  http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Show the code that is causing the error

Comment: @Pekka I have updated with the code.

Comment: that has nothing to do with `strtotime()` - it's more likely that `$lengths[$j]` is zero. Add a check that prevents the division from happening if that is the case

Comment: I copy and pasted this, I am not good with PHP math, could you help me out and provide an answer?

Comment: Maybe you should learn basics of PHP syntax before trying to just copy/paste other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) like this:

```
$tm = strptime($time, '%m%d%Y');
$timestamp = strtotime(sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $tm['tm_year'], $tm['tm_mon']+1, $tm['tm_mday']));
```

If you use PHP 5.3 or above, you can also use [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)

As for the other part of your question, your code has a bug if time difference is greater than 10 years.

What's the initial value of difference before any division? My guess is that it is more than 10 years, so you run out of "lengths", i.e. system tries to reach $lengths[8] which is not defined, which counts as zero, so it tries to divide by that zero.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on your second line

Comment: missing close bracket at end of second line

Comment: Still says can't divide by zero.

Comment: I fixed the bracket. I really don't see how those 2 lines I wrote can report division by zero error, when there is no division in the code. Division by zero is obviously in your code from above, which is something completely different from the title of your question.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov , the entire script is posted in the question. There's nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

starting, first line of the function `$difference = time() - $timestamp;` references $timestamp which is not set because `$timeToSend` is what is passed into the function. this causes $difference to always be equal to `time()`.

second, the divide by zero error is from the for loop `for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)` getting to a point where `$lengths[j]` doesn't exist (because of the first error, $difference==0) and so the looping continues until `$j` goes beyond the bounds of `$lengths`. I would suggest putting a check for `$lengths[$j]` inside the for loop like `for($j = 0; array_key_exists($j,$lengths)&&$difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)`.

final:

```
function RelativeTime($timeToSend){
$difference = time() - $timestamp;
$periods = array("sec", "min", "hour", "day", "week",
"month", "years", "decade");
$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

if ($difference > 0) { // this was in the past
$ending = "ago";
} else { // this was in the future
$difference = -$difference;
$ending = "to go";
}
for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)
$difference /= $lengths[$j];
$difference = round($difference);
if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
$text = "$difference $periods[$j] $ending";
return $text;
}
echo RelativeTime(strtotime('-3 months'))."\n";
echo RelativeTime(strtotime(0));
```

[And example working.](http://ideone.com/M4emt#)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, very well written!! I am still getting a Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/50/5975650/html/checkEntry.php on line 75  The line is: $difference /= $lengths[$j];

Comment: @JDAudi try adding braces `{ and }` to the for loop and then echo out `$j` along with `$lengths[$j]` to find out if/where $j is running out of bounds on $lengths.